# Sort list of objects using natural sort

Tags: c#, sorting, natural-sort

I have a class

```
class grpa
{
    public string file_name { get; set; }
    public string folder_name { get; set; }
}
```

I also have 2 lists of strings.

```
List<string> actualfiles = new List<string>();
List<string> directoryfiles= new List<string>();
```

I'm using an enumerator to create a list of objects of type grpa

```
IEnumerator enume1 = actualfiles.GetEnumerator();
IEnumerator enume2 = directoryfiles.GetEnumerator();

List<grpa> grp_list = new List<grpa>();
while ((enume1.MoveNext()) && (enume2.MoveNext()))
{
    grp_list.Add(new grpa
    {
      file_name = enume1.Current.ToString(),
      folder_name = enume2.Current.ToString() 
    });
}
```

I would like to sort the list after file_name using natural sort:
I have this:

```
public static class SafeNativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
}

public sealed class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    #region IComparer<string> Members

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(x, y);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

If it would have been a normal string list I could have sort it using: `actualfiles.Sort(new NaturalStringComparer());`
But how can I sort `grp_list`after `file_name`?

Answer (score 4):

Just use linq

```
var sorted = grp_list.OrderBy(x=>x.file_name, new NaturalStringComparer ()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write another `IComparer`, this time `IComparer<grpa>`:

```
public sealed class GrpaComparer : IComparer<grpa>
{
    public int Compare(grpa x, grpa y)
    {
        return SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(x.file_name, y.file_name);
    }
}
```

With that you sort your list:

```
grp_list.Sort(new GrpaComparer());
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [L.B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025787/80274), however instead of using LINQ to sort the resulting list, use LINQ to do all the work at once, the operation you are doing with the two enumerables is a [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
List<grpa> grp_list = actualfiles.Zip(directoryfiles, 
         (fileName, folderName) => new grpa { file_name = fileName, folder_name = folderName })
      .OrderBy(x=>x.file_name, new NaturalStringComparer())
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap NaturalString comparer with:

```
public sealed class GrpaComparer : IComparer<grpa>
{
    private IComparer<String> nsComparer;

    public GrpaComparer(IComparer<String> nsComparer) 
    {
      // Validate input for non-nullness
      this.nsComparer = nsComparer;
     }

    public int Compare(grpa x, grpa y)
    {
        return this.nsComparer.compare (x.file_name, y.file_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the file extension name before sorting and use 
`List.Sort()`. It might work give it a shot.